# Store path/filename of oracle script that is running

Tags: oracle

For audit purposes, I want to be able to store the path/filename of script used to create rows.

For example, if I use C:\oracle_scripts\my_oracle_script.sql to create data, then I want to be able store "C:\oracle_scripts\my_oracle_script.sql" in a column so I can know what script was used to create the data.

Is there a "session variable" or somesuch that I can used to dynamically access the path/filename of the running script without having to hardcode it?

Comment: Runing sqlplus?  Store in what column? see here https://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Getting-the-name-of-currently-executing-sql-script-in-sqlplus,5

Comment: I think you could do this by building it into the cilent/script you're using - but I can't imagine a way for the database to determine this from a session. It can take the module/program name and even the command/statement being executed in a session, but not determine the directory/script name

Comment: You can do it with a little bit of trickery described here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17347/sqlplus-and-relative-paths

Comment: @OldProgrammer that solution looks great but I am getting ORA-00922 error trying to run SET APPINFO ON in sqlplus.  Permissions issue?  I am an Oracle user not an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. There is a session variable that stores the program that is running the script, stored in `V$SESSION.PROGRAM`, but not the filename of the script.

However, the session variable most commonly used for your purpose is called `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.METHOD`. It is not bound to scripts, but can be used by other input methods as well (data changed by GUI etc).

To use it, you'll set the value in your script

```
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('my_oracle_script.sql','');
```

and read it inside the database, for instance in a trigger, with

```
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.READ_MODULE()
```

Futhermore, there a two other session variables `ACTION` and `CLIENT_INFO`.

Those variables are even tracked in the data dictionary views `V$SESSION` and `V$SQLAREA`, so if a script is running too long or is misbehaving in another way, a DBA can easily track the session and the executed SQL of the script.

Examples and more info on 
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS65225

Comment: interesting idea but if this value is hard-coded in script then what is the difference between using that and just setting a variable in the script?

Comment: 1. Clarity: Every experienced Oracle programmer will immediately understand what `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('my_oracle_script.sql','step1')` does and how to read the values

Comment: 2. Detail: Besides `METHOD` there is also `ACTION`, so you can give more details of where you are in your script, or what you are doing.

Comment: 3. Standard: It's well known, well understood and used by all the relevant tools. SQL Developer displays it in Monitor sessions, Cloud control shows it, it's reported in the trace files, you can even create a SQL Tuning Set based on `METHOD` and `ACTION`: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sqltun.htm#ARPLS68454